# Using single cell in loop as trigger to to copy multiple ranges VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

The macro is working with hard coded inputs but I need loops for debugging and future growth.  I don't know the best way to set this up.

Range("b3:b8:) are the cells I would like to loop over.

If cell.value = 1 then
Set var1 = range("a3:aq3")  (* This range always has the same row number as cell in loop*)

Set var2 = range("a9:aq9")  (*This range always 6 greater than row of cell in loop.)

End if

Next cell
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Loop Through Rows of a Range

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughRows()
    
    Const srgAddress As String = "A3:AQ8"
    Const scCol As Long = 2
    Const sCriteria As String = "1"
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ActiveSheet ' improve, e.g.:
    'Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    'Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(srgAddress) ' last use of 'sws'
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    
    Dim srg1 As Range
    Dim srg2 As Range
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim sr As Long
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Columns(scCol).Cells ' don't forget '.Cells'!
        sr = sr + 1 ' monitoring each range row (not worksheet row)
        If CStr(sCell.Value) = sCriteria Then ' also avoiding error values
            Set srg1 = srg.Rows(sr)
            Set srg2 = srg1.Offset(srCount)
            ' Continue... e.g.:
            Debug.Print sr, sCell.Address(0, 0), _
                srg1.Address(0, 0), srg2.Address(0, 0)
        Else ' not equal to sCriteria (usually do nothing)
            ' e.g.:
            Debug.Print sr, sCell.Address(0, 0), "Nope."
        End If
    Next sCell
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!  That looks like a lot of work.  I have been able to get parts of it to run., but I have been unable to get any criteria's to evaluate as true.  When you commented ' don't forget '.Cells'!  What is supposed to go in there?

Comment: The `.Cells` thing is just a reminder because it doesn't work without it. You have posted a link to your file but it asks to send a request. I've sent the request but you didn't allow it yet. Next time if you would like for people to be able to download your file, right-click on it, select `Get Link`, and instead of `Restricted` choose `Anyone with a link`.

Comment: My apologies.  Here is is with anyone with link.  Thanks for you patience.                                                                  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-5HUN3g6KDHtFzSxc1IZfS8YjAgzO6D9/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100729417742530875863&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: The code works on your file. You can even get the `sell only` associated row range with `Dim srg3 As Range: Set srg3 = srg2.Offset(srCount)`. But I don't know what you're planning to do with those ranges. If you're planning to copy to another worksheet, you need to explain or show how the resulting worksheet should look like.

Comment: I got it working!!  Thank you so much.  I believe I up voted you.  If not let me know how and I will.  You saved me so much time.

Comment: You can additionally accept the answer by ticking the checkmark to the left of it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a for loop?

Eg:

```
For Each Cell in Range("B3:B8")
  If Cell.Value = 1 Then
    Set var1 = range("a3:aq3")
  Else
    Set var2 = range("a9:aq9")
  End If
Next Cell
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That is exactly the kind of think I want.  The only change I need is when evaluating B4,  I need the two ranges to change as well.  So B4 would need ("a4:aq4:) and ("a10:aq10").  If B5 is true, I  would need to set the ranges as ("a5:aq5") and ("a11:aq11").  Short version is the range copied needs to dynamically change with the cell that evaluates as true.

Comment: Glad it helped.  Do you mind sending a snapshot/s of the outcomes you want and I will try do the code and post it later?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-5HUN3g6KDHtFzSxc1IZfS8YjAgzO6D9/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100729417742530875863&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Not sure the best way to send a snapshot.  As the sheet looks now, when the range("b3:b8") is evaluated,  "B4" evaluates as true and needs to set var1 = range(a4:aq4") and var2 = range("a4:aq4").  "B7" is also true so in that loop it would need to set var1 =  range("a7:aq7") and var2 = range("a13:aq13") .  I have a line of code at the start of the loop to move the latest records out of the way so the second time it is triggered it is not overwriting the "B4" entries.